# Não está compilando!E não acho resposta!

Tags: c

Não quer compilar...

```
 #include <stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>

    int main()
    {  
        system("title-Ajust System:Windows 7");//declarada-Title
        printf("SYSTEM 00.1-BETA\n\n");//-Name
        system("ver");//versão windows
        system("color 2");//cor

        for(system("time"))
   //Ajuste da Hora(Não está compilando)
       { 

          int time;

          if(time=0;time>0;time++)
          {
            printf("Erro ao alterar a hora...\n");//mensagem de erro
          }
          else
          {
           printf("Hora alterada com sucesso\n")//mensagem de hora alterada
          }

       }

       for (system("date"));//Ajuste da data(Não estou conseguindo compilar )
       {
        int date;

        if(date=0 ;date>0; date++)
           {
            printf("Erro ao alterar a data...\n");//mensagem de erro
           }
           else
           {
            printf("Data alterada com sucesso!\n");//mensagem de data alterada
           }
       }


       for(system("tree"));//manuseador de arquivos(também está dando erro)
       {
        int tree;

        if(tree=0; tree>0;tree++)
           {
            printf("Erro ao mostrar arquivos\n");//mensagem de erro
           }
           else
           {
            printf("arquivos abertos com sucesso!\n";)//mensagem de arquivos abertos
           }
       }

       /*
       Obs.:O programa tem como base manusear o sistema operacional com mais facilida
       de,caso tenha uma ideia continue com a linha de código...
       */

          return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Esse código não compila porque ele é quase aleatório, seria interessante estudar um pouco mais o assunto antes de tentar escrever alguma coisa.

Comment: Não está faltando um ponto e vírgula no segundo printf (ali no primeiro else)?

Comment: sim obrigado cara!

Answer (score 0):

Bem, creio que nesse código está muita coisa mal. A estrutura do for, está errada e deveria ser if, e quando tem if, essa estrutura é do for. Não sei o que pretende fazer, mas é óbvio que isso está mal, além disso usa ; nessas condições, e isso implica que não execute o que está dentro do for e do if.
no if, usa-se esta estrutura: `if(condição)`, e no for usa-se `for(i=0;i<10;i++)` por exemplo, ou seja, vai fazer um ciclo for desde i=0 até que i ser menor que 10, e vai andando sempre +1.
Você está a usar no if condições do for, e no for condições do if, e não pode ter ; 
Creio que será por isso que o código não compila

Comment: Eu costumo fazer o código de qualquer forma para corrigir depois,mas eu estava me confundindo as  condições do for e do if!obrigado pela ajuda!